# MVVM light - push notifications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, push-notification, mvvm-light

I am trying to learn MVVM Light and used it for my Windows Phone 8 application. It's working great but I can't find any tutorials or samples how to use Push Notifications with MVVM pattern.

In my MainPage I set HttpNotificationChannel and I am receiving notifications:

```
void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            string relativeUri = string.Empty;

            message.AppendFormat("Received Toast {0}:\n", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

            // Parse out the information that was part of the message.
            foreach (string key in e.Collection.Keys)
            {
                message.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", key, e.Collection[key]);

                if (string.Compare(
                    key,
                    "wp:Param",
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    relativeUri = e.Collection[key];
                }
            }

            // Display a dialog of all the fields in the toast.
            //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(message.ToString()));

        }
```

Now I am not sure what to do. I would receive about 5 different kind of notifications which should navigate app to different pages in app or refresh page (or maybe save some data to storage). How can I do that? When I was searching I find some messaging system in mvvm light. Could I use that for notifications? Which types of messages should I use? Could you give me some example code or point me to tutorial (article/video). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely use MVVMlight's messaging system since this gives you a clean and losely coupled callback that your viewmodels can subscribe to.

In your push notification service class expose a couple of public message strings that your viewmodel can listen for:

```
public static readonly string REFRESHCONTENTMESSAGE = "RefreshContent";
public static readonly string DELETECONTENTMESSAGE = "DeleteContent";
```

Then subscribe to the messenger in your viewmodel:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, HandleMessage);
```

Lastly set up the handler:

```
public void HandleMessage(NotificationMessage message) {
    if (message.Notification.Equals(YourService.REFRESHCONTENTMESSAGE))
    {
        // Do stuff like navigating to a page.
    }
    else if (message.Notification.Equals(YourService.DELETECONTENTMESSAGE))
    {
        // Do something else.
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is to send a message from your push notification service class when a new notification is received:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage(REFRESHCONTENTMESSAGE));
```

This is just a brief version. If you're looking for a version that can actually carry data around, go for a NotificationMessage with content (and adjust the code above with the generic aspect):

```
Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage<MyObject>>(new NotificationMessage<MyObject>(REFRESHCONTENTMESSAGE));

// In your handler:
MyObject payload = message.Content;
```

If you need a deeper level of customization, you COULD write your own message types. But I think you'll do okay with the existing ones. The advantage would be that you could explicitly only listen for your special message type which would reduce the message traffic inside your application if you would send around a critical number of messages.

Comment: @Fred - unfortunately the messenger has nothing to do with MVVM.  How would you solve this using MVVM?

Comment: @O.O - He is talking about the Messenger that is build in the the MVVM Light library. It is useful for Making calls in your base class that your UI code can subscribe and respond to, thus allowing more of your code to be platform agnostic.